# Position_controllers/JointPositionController is missing from the moveit setup assistant

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Description**

After updating to ubuntu 20.04, I tried to create a new config file using moveit setup assistant. However, position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController was identified in the ROS Control pane selector, but position_controllers/JointPositionController was missing.

**My environment**

ROS Distro: [noetic]

OS Version: Ubuntu 20.04

**Steps to reproduce :**

https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html

I followed the link above to proceed with the movement setup assistant tutorial.

**Expected behaviour :**

Select Position_controllers/Joint Position Controller from the ROS Control pane selector.

**Actual behaviour :**

Position_controllers/JointPositionController does not exist in the option.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394851/please-help!!-position_controllers/jointpositioncontroller-is-missing-from-the-moveit-setup-assistant./) by [sm3304ove](https://answers.ros.org/users/90076/sm3304ove/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-24**:
Cross-posted to [ros-planning/moveit#3033](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/3033) *and* [ros-planning/moveit_tutorials#698](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/issues/698).

Please do not cross-post like this.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> However, position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController was identified in the ROS Control pane selector, but position_controllers/JointPositionController was missing.

I believe this is expected, as MoveIt cannot directly use a plain `JointPositionController`.

It needs a `JointTrajectoryController`. That's why you only see those in the dropdown.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sm3304ove](https://answers.ros.org/users/90076/sm3304ove/) on 2022-01-24**:
So should I choose JointTrajectoryController?
I used to be able to select Position_controllers/JointPositionController in ubuntu 18.04, why is it gone in the noetic version?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may happen if the position controller package is not installed for some reason.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-position-controllers
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sm3304ove](https://answers.ros.org/users/90076/sm3304ove/) on 2022-01-24**:
I tried the method you suggested, but it says the latest version is already installed.